# How i can access an object in php

Tags: php

Please see object array which i print here:

SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [generator-info-name] => www.ontv.dk/xmltv
        )

```
[channel] => Array
    (
        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => www.ontv.dk/tv/1
                    )

                [display-name] => DR1 DK
            )
```

)

How I can access channel-->display-name

Below code is not working:

echo $obj->channel[0]->display-name;

Help me please

Answer (score 2):

Property names with dashes must be quoted properly:

```
echo $obj->channel[0]->{'display-name'};
```

Otherwise, the parser sees it as an arithmetic operation (i.e: $obj->channel[0]->display **minus** name).

Comment: When i try to convert this string in different array for example :for($i=0;$i<=count($s->channel);$i++){
 $ChannelName[] = $s->channel[$i]->{'display-name'};
} It return me again an object like ==>Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [lang] => dk
                )

            [0] => DR1 DK
        )

)
I need to convert again into array

Comment: You need a recursive function to transform nested objects into arrays. See the comments on [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) for examples.